# What is += mean in python and why should i use it?

Tags: python, operators

I was wondering what the += operator does in python. What is it used for and why would i use it?

Comment: `x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y`.  You couldn't be bothered to do a google search on "python operators"??

Comment: Why would i want to use it?

Comment: Because this way you don't have to re-type the first variable name, which  means less typing and fewer chances to make a dumb mistake (i.e. what if you meant to type `x1 = x1 + y1` but instead you typed `x1 = y1 + y1`?  You might not even notice, and then spend hours or days tracking down the bug.)

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out, `x += y` is similar to `x = x + y`.

One notable difference being that the `+=` operator is an "in-place" operation. So `x += y` is actually "in-place add". Which means, it modifies the object 'x'.

Whereas `x = x + y` adds the values of 'x' and 'y' and stores the result (as a new object) in 'x', discarding its previous value. This becomes more important when dealing with objects, custom numerical types or in any user-defined class where the behaviour can be modified internally.

`+` calls the object's [`__add__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) method.
`+=` calls [`__iadd__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).
(It can get more complicated, with `__radd__`, etc. but I'm glossing over that for now.)

One good reason to use `+=` is: depending on the object type, `x += y` can be optimised in specific cases, but `x = x + y` has to create a new object to re-assign to 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

```
a += b
```

is similar to :

```
a = a + b
```

It also works with other basic signs, for instance :

```
a *= b
```

is similar to :

```
a = a * b
```

Answer (score 0):

The other usage is for string, str += 'defg' is the same as str = str + 'defg'

```
str = 'abc'
str += 'defg'
print(str)
'abcdefg'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as augmented assignment, and it is not peculiar to the Python language.  The advantage is not just saved typing.  There is a computational advantage, since `x+=1` evaluates `x` only once by `x=x+1` evaluates `x` twice.  See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements